# MD5 Hashing all files in a directory

Tags: python, hash, directory, md5

I am trying to make a program that loops over all my files in a directory and make then all md5 hash codes.

```
import hashlib, os, sys
for root, dirs,files in os.walk("C:\Users\Matt\AppData\NewFolder", topdown=True):
    for name in files:
        #print(os.path.join(root, name))
FileName = (os.path.join(root, name))

hasher = hashlib.md5()
with open(str(FileName), 'rb') as afile:
    buf = afile.read()
    hasher.update(buf)
print(hasher.hexdigest())
```

If someone would be willing to help me out that would be great.

Comment: Are number of spaces correct in your posted code? What is the problem with your current code? Did you try to hash single file?

Comment: the code works on single files but im trying to hash everything in the folder at once

Comment: At the present state, this code will produce `IndentationError`

Comment: let me fix that i know what is wrong its not an indentationError. ill edit the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move your file reading and hashing code to be inside the loop body.

```
import hashlib, os, sys

for root, dirs,files in os.walk("C:\Users\Matt\AppData\NewFolder", topdown=True):
    for name in files:
        #print(os.path.join(root, name))
        FileName = (os.path.join(root, name))

        hasher = hashlib.md5()
        with open(str(FileName), 'rb') as afile:
            buf = afile.read()
            hasher.update(buf)
        print(hasher.hexdigest())
```

Comment: Also, keep in mind that MD5 is considered weak at the this point, and shouldn't be used for anything security-related. An better alternative is SHA-256.

Comment: Great answer. However, you didn't seem to utilize the library `sys`. Is there a reason that you imported it? Thanks.